# Creating a Rails model to manage a table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

```
Rails 3.2
```

I have a table:

```
subscriptions_locations
```

with two columns:

```
subscription_id
location_id
```

that's currently not part of the application, can I manage it via ActiveRecord, if I create a model subscriptions_location.rb:

```
class SubscriptionsLocation < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :subscription_id, :location_id
end
```

and anytime I want to add or delete, I can do something like:

```
SubscriptionsLocation.find_by_subscription_id("some_subscription_id").destroy
```

and

```
sub_location = SubscriptionsLocation.new(:subscription_id => "something", :location_id => "something")
sub_location.save!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that's correct, you have all the points right.

but you don't even need this part, because no matter if you haven't created the table with rails, the attributes will be accesible.

```
attr_accessible :subscription_id, :location_id
```

just have in mind that if you later need to move the application to production, that table will not be in the migrations and you will always need to add this table manually in this case.

maybe you can create a migration that creates the table with a validation

```
create_table :subscriptions_locations if !(table_exists? :subscriptions_locations)
```